make animation return to initial value (background-color)
I have a box that I want to blink.

it should blink indefinitely (infinite)
it blinks to white and returns to the initial color
there should be a "pause" between each loop (color stays the same)
css only, no js

This snippet fulfils all criteria. 30% and 70% keyframes are for the pause between each loop where it stays fully green. In between it blinks to white.
But this example uses hardcoded colors. Is it possible to just have the color set for the object (here body)? Then the box blinks to white und back to its original color, no matter what color the box has at the time. Using "inherit" oder "initial" in the keyframes unfortunately returns it to white.


body {
  animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
  30% {background-color: green;}
  50% {background-color: white;}
  70% {background-color: green;}
}




A more simple code using the new linear() timing function


body {
  animation: blink 3s infinite linear(0, 0 30%, 1 50%, 0 70%, 0);
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {background-color: white;}
}




The linear() function only works in the latest versions of browsers.

To solve this, you can use revert-layer to return to the previously set value:


body {
  animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
  30%, 70% { background-color: revert-layer; }
  50% { background-color: white; }
}



Compared to linear(), revert-layer is supported by earlier browsers.

Update
Unfortunately linear() is not supported by win 7 bowsers
Free translation  answer from the user  @UModeL.

Use a css variable.


for( let button of document.querySelectorAll("button") ) {
  button.addEventListener( "click", setBlinkColor )
}

function setBlinkColor( event ) {
  document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--BlinkColor',event.target.innerText)
}
#Block1 {
  --BlinkColor: #F80;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--BlinkColor);
  background-color: var(--BlinkColor);
}

#Block2 {
  --BlinkColor: #83F;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--BlinkColor);
  background-color: var(--BlinkColor);
}

body {
  height: 300px;
  --BlinkColor: #cab;
  animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--BlinkColor);
}

@keyframes blink {
  30% {background-color: var(--BlinkColor);}
  50% {background-color: white;}
  70% {background-color: var(--BlinkColor);}
}
<button>RED</button>
<button>GREEN</button>
<button>BLUE</button>



<div id="Block1">
</div>

<div id="Block2">
</div>




Are these local to the element? Like if I have multiple boxes to apply this to - do I need them all to have different css-var-names to be independent or can they be the same?

you can create a default variable, and inside each element override the default one if needed. I'm updating my example with a demo.

What @Eloi said :-)

hhahaha at the end we have the same solution xD

that seems to be what I am looking for - thanks both!

If what you need is some kind of dynamic setting, you can use css variables.


:root {
    --bg-color: green;
}

.h-33 {
    height: 33vh;
}

.blink {
    animation: blink 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.blink-green {
    --bg-color: green;
}

.blink-blue {
    --bg-color: blue;
}

@keyframes blink {
    30% {background-color: var(--bg-color);}
    50% {background-color: white;}
    70% {background-color: var(--bg-color);}
}
<div class="h-33 blink blink-green">

</div>
<div class="h-33 blink blink-blue">

</div>
<div class="h-33 blink" style="--bg-color: purple;">

</div>



